# Move from manual install to use Realm through Cocoapods in Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, realm, cocoapods

I’m currently using Realm in one of my projects, where I manually installed it. Everything was working fine until I updated Xcode from 10.1 to 10.2. Now I keep getting the following error.

> Module compiled with Swift 4.2 cannot be imported by the Swift 5.0 compiler: /Users/userName/MyApp/RealmSwift.framework/Modules/RealmSwift.swiftmodule/i386.swiftmodule

I believe this has to do with the fact that when I try to replace the `Realm frameworks` in my project with the newest `Realm` compiled for Xcode 10.2, Xcode doesn’t copy the files, it just references them even when having the **Copy Files If Needed** option checked.

Anyways, I now would like to try using `Realm` through `Cocoapods` to eliminate this kind of issues every time I update Xcode, so my questions are…

1. What do I need to change in Xcode in order for me to move from manual install to use Realm through Cocoapods?
2. What do I need in Framework Search Paths?
3. Do I need to remove the `Run Script Phase`
   *bash "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${FRAMEWORKS_FOLDER_PATH}/Realm.framework/strip-frameworks.sh"*?
4. What do I need in my Pod file? I’m more interested to see how I would incorporate `Realm` for my `WatchApp Extension` since I couldn’t find any info in the documentation.

Here is how my Pod file looks like right now.

### Pod File

```
#platform :ios, '9.3'

target 'MyApp' do
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for MyApp
  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'NVActivityIndicatorView'

  target 'MyAppTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
  end

  target 'MyAppUITests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
  end
end

target 'MyApp Watch App' do
  use_frameworks!

end

target 'MyApp Watch App Extension' do
  use_frameworks!

end
```

FYI - I’m already using Cocoapods in my project but not for `Realm` yet. Also, I’m using `Realm` for `iOS` and `WatchApp Extension` in this project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have the workspace created by cocoapods, you don't need to modify your project settings, when you add a new pod to your podfile, cocoapods will automatically handle linking that to your project correctly.

Simply remove the manually added Realm framework files, remove the custom Run Script build phase containing `"${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${FRAMEWORKS_FOLDER_PATH}/Realm.framework/strip-frameworks.sh"`, then run `pod update` and you should be good to go.

As for the original issue of

> Module compiled with Swift 4.2 cannot be imported by the Swift 5.0 compiler: /Users/userName/MyApp/RealmSwift.framework/Modules/RealmSwift.swiftmodule/i386.swiftmodule

, when using precompiled frameworks, you need to wait until the developer of the framework updates the precompiled versions for Swift 5 (or the newest version you want to switch your project to) before you can use them.

Since cocoapods compiles all dependencies from source on your own machine, this issue of incompatible Swift compiler versions cannot arise and you can even control which Swift version to use for each project specifically from your podfile.

Comment: David Pasztor - Can you please clarify the following statement, **when using precompiled frameworks, you need to..** are you saying that `Realm` is not ready to be used in `Xcode 10.2` yet? I'm using Swift 4.2 in my project and I thought you could run Swift 4.2 inside Xcode 10.2. Also, how can I add `Realm` to my Watch App Extension in my `Pod` file? I tried `target 'MyApp Watch App Extension' do
  use_frameworks! pod 'RealmSwift' end` but I got a bunch of error messages. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @fs_tigre I haven't checked the latest release of Realm, but when you download the latest release of Realm manually, you can check which Swift versions it supports. You need to switch your project to Swift 4.2 if you want to use a Realm version compiled with Swift 4.2. What error messages do you get with your podfile?

Comment: @ David Pasztor - Can you please add to your answer the fact that the `Run Script Phase` bash `"${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${FRAMEWORKS_FOLDER_PATH}/Realm.framework/strip-frameworks.sh"` must be removed along with the frameworks so I can mark your answer as the correct one. I know this may seem obvious but I originally thought that the scripts needed to stay and of course I was getting the same error I described in my original question until I removed the script.

Comment: @fs_tigre oh yeah, I forgot to mention that, updated my answer